# MinSDK and TaretSDK android , How does compilation and linking actually occurs at runtime?

Tags: android

Pardon my ignorance in this subject, what I know is that SDK is a set of headers and libs which are used as a support for compiling an application.

Now In android there are 2 concepts minSDK and TargetSDK. The documentation says that you compile against the TargetSDK.

So  I a bit confused, How does 2 SDKs are used in compilation.
How does linking happen at run time.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only *specification* determined use is by the play store (or anything that may need to manipulate apks.) An .apk is a zip with a (possibly binary) version of the manifest.xml in it. The play store looks this up and uses it to prevent customers on their store from downloading apps that don't support their api version.

I do not necessary interpret the specification as saying that the target SDK version will be used to build- far from it; the manifest isn't extensively checked at compile time. This field in the manifest only tells google that you've *tested* your app at the target SDK level and turns on compatibility modes for higher still API versions. I quote:

> For example, setting this value to "11" or higher allows the system to apply a new default theme (Holo) to your app when running on Android 3.0 or higher and also disables screen compatibility mode when running on larger screens (because support for API level 11 implicitly supports larger screens).

For further reading see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

So if you're interested what determines the api used to build against, you're looking to add a line like `target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:17` to `project.properites`.

I, practically speaking, recommend using `project.properties` to build the app against your *minimum* version until you start QA however, since if you accidentally use methods of a former SDK version you get told at compile time.